# Spring REST API not showing /players despite following tutorial?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-rest

I am developing a SpringBoot REST API, and have been following a tutorial. I have followed this tutorial before and everything worked fine, yet now when I call:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/players
```

I get a 404 error:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-11-05T15:05:07.850+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/api/players"}
```

Domain:

```
    @Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {

    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String bio;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Player player = (Player) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, player.id) &&
                Objects.equals(firstName, player.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(lastName, player.lastName) &&
                Objects.equals(email, player.email) &&
                Objects.equals(bio, player.bio);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, firstName, lastName, email, bio);
    }
}
```

Repo:

```
    public interface PlayerRepository extends CrudRepository<Player, Long> {

}
```

Database Loader:

```
    @Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final PlayerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseLoader(PlayerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        this.repository.save(new Player(1L, "Magnus", "Carlsen", "magnuscarlsen@gmail.com", "I am world champion."));

    }
}
```

SpringApplication:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application Properties:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

As I say, I really don't understand why it's not working as I have checked everything twice and it should work, just like it did the first time I followed this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

Thanks for any help!

```
    curl http://localhost:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>ReactJS + Spring Data REST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="react"></div>

<script src="built/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
curl http://localhost:8080/api
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in this question related to React. Just because you're using React in the app, doesn't necessarily mean it should be tagged in the question. Am I missing something, or is it truly irrelevant?

Comment: @BrianThompson Well someone who has used React with SpringBoot might know what is wrong? I'll untag it anyway but that was my thinking

Comment: If you believe the problem may be related to React, or how you are fetching the data in React, then yes it could be relevant. But if you believe it's relevant to the problem you should include why in your question, and possibly the JS code used to fetch the data. However, this seems unlikely, and React doesn't provide any fetching functionality itself, so it would really just be a JavaScript issue and not specific to React.

Comment: @BrianThompson It's nothing to do with React tbh it was just because the project is React + SB

Comment: Does anything come up when you type [http://localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080)? @JoeBailey

Comment: @İsmailY. Yes, added to question the response, works fine but /api only shows /profile not /players. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeBailey, can you please add the package of each of your classes? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias My packages for each class (controller, domain etc) were all outside the correct directory, I refactored and now it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: I will post it as an answer so that you can accept it and let the ticket be "closed" so that others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the packages of all your classes. They should be sub packages of the package where your main `Application` class is.